# Right Click to select items in a ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, select, listbox, right-click

I'm trying to make a list of items that you can do several actions with by right-clicking and having a context menu come up. I've completed that, no problem whatsoever.

But I'd like to have it so that when you right click on a item, instead of leaving the current item selected, to select the item the mouse is over.

I've researched this and other related questions, and I've tried to use indexFromPoint (which I found through my research) but whenever I right click on a item, it always just clears the selected item and doesn't show the context menu, as I have it set so that it wont appear if there is no selected item.

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
ListBox.SelectedIndex = ListBox.IndexFromPoint(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
```

Comment: This looks like a bug in System.Windows.Forms.ListBox, we should report it to Microsoft.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Handle `ListBox.MouseDown` and select the item in there. Like this:

```
private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y);
}
```

Comment: If context menu is already bounded to the listbox, just use:
private void listBoxItems_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        listBoxItems.SelectedIndex = listBoxItems.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y);
    }

Answer (score 12):

**this one is working...**

```
this.ListBox.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.List_RightClick);

private void List_RightClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        int index = this.listBox.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
        if (index != ListBox.NoMatches)
        {
            listBox.Items[index];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Just replaced this line listBox.Items[index]; with .SelectedIndex = index; and this works perfectly.

Comment: Weird that the click event doesn't seem to capture the right button or the middle button.  Have to use MouseUp to capture them..

Answer (score 0):

Can also get same behaviour by setting a MouseRightButtonUp event on the whole listbox then:

```
private void AccountItemsT33_OnMouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // If have selected an item via left click, then do a right click, need to disable that initial selection
    AccountItemsT33.SelectedIndex = -1;
    VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(e.GetPosition(null), (sender as ListBox)).OfType<ListBoxItem>().First().IsSelected = true;
}
```