# c# mouse left click on listbox

Tags: c#, listbox, click

How can I execute an function when mouse left click on a Item in listbox ? 
I Can't use SelectChanged because I listen also right click, and when I right click on the item it's execute the fuction SelectChanged also.

Or how to detect in SelectChange method, if event it's right click or left

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220501/right-click-to-select-items-in-a-listbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listBoxG.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonUpEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnMouseLeftButtonUp_listBoxG), true);

public void OnMouseLeftButtonUp_listBoxG(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
// something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**WPF:**

XAML: install System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF nuget library

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:test="clr-namespace:Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <test:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxItems}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="216" Height="235" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp" >
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ListBoxLeftClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel.cs using the MVVMLight library for RelayCommand and ViewModelBase

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Input;

using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;

namespace Test
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public class TestModel
        {
            public string Value { get; set; }

            public TestModel(string value)
            {
                this.Value = value;
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> ListBoxItems { get; set; }

        public ICommand ListBoxLeftClickCommand { get; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            ListBoxLeftClickCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(DoSomething, selectedItem => true);
            ListBoxItems = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Test1", "Test2" };
        }

        private void DoSomething(object selectedItem)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**WinForms:**
taken from [Right Click to select items in a ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220501/right-click-to-select-items-in-a-listbox)

```
this.ListBox.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.List_LeftClick);

private void List_LeftClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        int index = this.listBox.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
        if (index != ListBox.NoMatches)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```